# Postgres - temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, database-cursor

I tried issuing a read all request (select * from tblName) using JDBC cursors (setFetchSize). The temp_file_limit property in postgresql.conf is 500 KB. When I execute the prepared statement, I get a psql exception -

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit (500kB)

The documentation in PostgreSQL.conf says "# limits per-session temp file space". 
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor as per this link, the connection must have disabled auto-commit and I had not disabled it. I did that as well, yet I ended up with the same issue. My understanding is that such large read operations are written to a temporary file before loading to the resultset. If this is the case then with a low temp_file_limit, I will never be able to read very large data, even with a cursor. This does not make sense to why it is made configurable in the first place.

Setting the temp_file_limit to -1 (unbounded file size) solved this issue for me. Am I correct in taking this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen queries that would use a lot of space (sometimes over 1TiB), kept going until all free space was used and other queries started crashing. Setting it to lets say reasonable (in our case) 100GiB would have protected other sessions.

Setting it to 500kB seems indeed pointless.

FYI temp files are used not only for cursors.

Comment: I read that temporary space is used for order by operations as well. I am yet to explore them fully. I will learn a bit more about that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The reason for specifically pointing out cursors was that I wanted to understand how cursors handle bulk reads. My thought was that cursors do write all the data to a temp file, so as to provide a snapshot of the operation. This will not be possible otherwise IMO. If cursors operated differently (read from DB per fetch operation) then the 500 kB limit should not be the problem. I wanted to ensure that my understanding was correct. Am I?

Comment: @kishore I didn't see it at a glance in documentation, but I suspect that they are working in similar way to having repeatable read isolation level, so basically snapshot of table, using old tuples if some rows were changed - assuming they aren't affected by commits by other transactions. I did open cursor on 82GiB table, fetched a few rows and it created 0 temp files during this operation. Documentation implies that it holds parts of the set in memory.